# How to pass parameter to a @Component class which can't be autowired in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

I am building a desktop application using JavaFx and Spring Boot and I am stuck at some problem

I have `@Component` class `Translator` which extends `Task<String>` and makes an api call to google translation api and I want to pass an autowired bean class and some string parameters such as source and target language to the `Translator` constructor.

```
@Component
class Translator extends Task<String>{

   private TextPreprocessor textPreprocessor;
   private Stirng strUrl;
   private String from;
   private String to;
   private String text;

   public Translator(@Value("${translator.api.url}" strUrl,TextPreprocessor textPreprocessor)){
      this.strUrl=strUrl;
      this.textPreprocessor=textPreprocessor;
   }

   protected String call() throws Exception{
    //some code 
   }


}
@Component
class TextPreprocessor{
 //some code
}
```

So my problem is I need to pass parameters `from`,`to` and `text` to Translator constructor but I can't do that here because these varibles can't be autowired. How can I fix this?

Comment: hmm .. this seems to be unrelated to javafx, or how is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your requirements the class `Translator` should not belong to `Spring-context` and it should not be a `spring-bean`. Instead it seems that this class should be instantiated manually by you in the code each time you need it so that you can pass dynamically the fields `from`, `to`, `text`.

In the class where you will manually instantiate `Translator` instances, you could have autowired `strUrl` and `textPreprocessor` as fields, so that they are always available for you to pass in the new instance of `Translator` that you will create.

There is 1 case where I would see it as a `spring-bean` and this would be if you moved `from`, `to`, `text` from been fields of this class into been parameters of method `call`. This way you could have `Translator` as a singleton retrieved from `Spring-context` and you could use dynamic values for `from`, `to`, `text` any time you would like to invoke call method.

The whole picture of your question seems like a design problem.